# Output image with correct aspect with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mkv video with the following properties (obtained with mediainfo):

```
Width                                    : 718 pixels
Height                                   : 432 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 2.35:1
Original display aspect ratio            : 2.35:1
```

I'd like to take screenshots of it at certain times:

```
ffmpeg -ss 4212 -i filename.mkv -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 out.jpg
```

This will produce a 718x432 jpg image, but the aspect ratio is wrong (the image is "squeezed" horizontally). AFAIK, the output image should be 1015*432 (with width=height * DAR). Is this calculation correct?

Is there a way to have ffmpeg output images with the correct size/AR for all videos (i.e. no "hardcoded" values)? I tried playing with the setdar/setsar filters without success.

Also, out of curiosity, trying to obtain SAR and DAR with ffmpeg produces:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709, progressive),
718x432 [SAR 64:45 DAR 2872:1215], SAR 155:109 DAR 55645:23544, 24.99 fps, 24.99 tbr, 1k tbn, 49.98 tbc (default)
```

2872/1215 is 2.363, so a slightly different value than what mediainfo reported. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without looking at the file, can't diagnose the reason for the distinct readings, but the generic method to get a square pixel result is

```
ffmpeg -ss 4212 -i filename.mkv -vf scale=iw*sar:ih -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 out.jpg
```

Comment: Use `-vf "scale='max(iw,iw*sar)':'max(ih,ih/sar)'"` to **always upscale**. `scale=iw*sar:ih` just randomly scales up or down depending on the display ratio being horizontal or vertical stretched.

Comment: The SAR indicates the transform for the width only. Anamorphic frames were originally designed for analogue bandwidth considerations. Take a NTSC signal, its digitized form is usually 704x480 with a sub-unit SAR of ~0.91. That's meant to yield a raster of 640x480, not 704x528 as your expr does.

Answer (score 0):

Accordin to the [doc of FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale)

```sh
ffmpeg -ss 4212 -i filename.mkv -vf scale='trunc(ih*dar):ih',setsar=1/1  \
    -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 out.jpg
```

making sure the resulting resolution is even (required by some codecs)